# Resize the queue on Grooveshark

Tags: grooveshark

I've been using Grooveshark for quite some time. Recently they have redesigned their site (the old site is still available at http://retro.grooveshark.com/). I can't find out where I can resize the current playlist and the cover art images.

In the old version it can be achieved by either clocking and dragging the four-horizontal-stripes button, or by clicking the "resize queue" button (4th icon in the image, before the gear and the volume slider).

[image]

However in the new version I can't find out how to change this setting. On different computers the images have different sizes and apparently no options on how to modify it.

Here's how it look on one of my computers (Chrome on Windows Vista):

[image]

Here's how it look on other of my computers (Firefox on ubuntu):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[According to Grooveshark officials](https://www.facebook.com/grooveshark/posts/10151185600276701), they removed manual queue resizing in favor of automatic size detection based on browser window size.

That's disappointing. So I've sat down and written this userscript: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/180288. It adds the good old button back:

[image: good old button]

Beware that the new Grooveshark UI only supports two queue sizes: "small" and "medium".

Edit: userscripts.org is down too often. Here is the alternative link: https://greasyfork.org/scripts/1664

Comment: This is obsolete now, since new Grooveshark UI doesn't have any buttons in queue.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to change size on automatic-sizing Grooveshark’s interface is to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> on your keyboard and scroll with your mouse wheel until it changes size again (same as you'd normally change size in your browser). This will, of course, change text size and everything else on the page as well, but works just fine IMO.